# How to pass custom prompt variables in a chainlit app?

Tags: chatbot, langchain, large-language-model, retrieval-augmented-generation

I want to add a simple chat UI to my RAG based chatbot. All the materials(one [example](https://medium.com/@cleancoder/build-a-chatbot-in-minutes-with-chainlit-gpt-4-and-langchain-7690968578f0)) I came across online have a very simple prompt template with `question` and `chat_history` variables. I do not see those variables being explicitly passed to the prompt in chainlit's `@on_message` method implementation. I assume that, by default, chainlit passes `message` param to `question` variable of prompt?

However my prompt has many more variables and I do not see how to pass them when invoking the `@on_message` decorated method of chainlit. I tried this but it does not work:

```
@cl.on_message
async def main(message: cl.message):
    chain = cl.user_session.get("chain")
    cb = cl.AsyncLangchainCallbackHandler()
    res = await chain.acall(inputs={
        "question": message,
        "chat_history": "",
        "doc_name": "Sample name",
        "contact_info": "Samplecontact@abc.com",
        "doc_url": "foo.com",
        "doc_owner": "Sample owner"
    }, callbacks=[cb])
    answer = res["answer"]
    await cl.Message(content=answer).send()
```

It gives an error `expected string or buffer` when I send a message on chainlit's UI. Screenshot attached.

[image: error-chainlit-chat]

Does anyone know how to send custom prompt variables via chainlit to the model? Checked chainlit's official doc as well but not helpful.
Chainlit seems like a framework with very high level abstraction and does too much "magic" under the covers! :(